# Establish the order of some values

Tags: php, sql

I have a series of queries that find out what is the best position every user had over a series of events (note: all users have the same `$points_pos`, so I am looking at a discriminating value). The query is looped for every user.

```
$max=$amount+1;
$i=1;
$highestsofar="99";

$numpointsall = "SELECT driver, position FROM standings_drivers WHERE season='42' AND points='$points_pos'";
$numall = mysql_query($numpointsall);
while ($i<$max) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($numall)) {
        $driver_id = $row[0];

        $posvar = "SELECT position FROM results WHERE compId='$compId' AND driverId='$driver_id' AND eventID>='$firstevent' AND eventID<='$lastevent' AND (eventSession!='T' AND eventSession!='P' AND eventSession!='Q' AND eventSession!='Q1' AND eventSession!='Q2' AND eventSession!='QA') ORDER BY position ASC LIMIT 1";
        $posres = mysql_query($posvar);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($posres)) {
            $highestpos = $row[0];
        }                   
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Having established the `$highestpos` for each of the `$driver_id`, how can I arrange them in order of best position (that is, the ones with the lowest `$highestpos`)?

Ideally, I want to achieve something that tells me:
`$driver_id = 1`
`$driver_id = 2` etc
so that I can amend a table by putting them in the correct order of position.

**EDIT: additional info**
The `results` table look like this:

```
ID    compId    eventId    eventSession    driverId    position
1     2         739        R               563         7
2     2         739        R               903         1
3     2         562        R               874         16
```

...

In the case above, assuming that 739 and 562 are the IDs of events in the range, I would like to order the three users in driverId as follows:
`903 = 1st`
`563 = 2nd`
`874 = 3rd`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you provided sample data and expected output along with your table structures. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TomH thank you - going to edit the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing about SQL is that it's typically much better than you (or I) are at getting data. The developers and architects for Microsoft, Oracle, etc. have spent a great deal of time and effort working on the best ways to select data, so trying to duplicate their efforts (like looping over results and getting values, etc.) is usually a mistake.

All of your code can likely be replaced with a single SQL query:

```
SELECT
    SD.driver,
    MIN(R.position) AS highest_position
FROM
    Standings_Drivers SD
INNER JOIN Results R ON
    R.driver = SD.driver AND
    R.compId = ? AND
    eventID >= ? AND
    eventID <= ? AND
    eventSession NOT IN ('T', 'P', 'Q', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'QA')
WHERE
    SD.season = '42' AND    -- Should this really be a string and not an integer?
    SD.points = ?
GROUP BY
    SD.driver
ORDER BY
    MIN(R.position)
```

The question marks are where you would pass in your various parameters. Make sure that you're are executing this as a parameterized query and not just building up a complete string. I don't program in PHP, so I don't know the syntax for that. Googling for "sql injection php" should help you out there though.

Comment: thank you for this. After the ON definition, should be a WHERE in place of the first of many AND (before R.compID)?

Comment: **EDIT**: I did this change and it works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Follow up - in case two users have the same best position, is there a way to find out what's the next best one (and then the next etc until a difference is found)?

Comment: A `JOIN` condition can contain multiple criteria, so unless you're using a non-ANSI compliant implementation of SQL (you didn't tag which type of SQL you're using) it shouldn't be a problem having the `WHERE` clause where it is. Personally, I prefer it this way because it's more organized in which criteria goes with which table.

For your other question I would suggest starting a new question.